# MySQL Trigger synatax

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to create a MySQL trigger to duplicate the auto increment column.

Auto increment column is called "iBmsId" and the duplicate column is called simply "id".

Here is my Query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t_bms_ID_Update AFTER INSERT ON t_bms SET id = iBmsId
```

I get the following error in SQL fiddle:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET id = iBmsId' at line 1:
```

Any ideas? This is the first time I have used Triggers...

Comment: Why would you want to do this!?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `after insert` and you can not update the same table within the trigger. So you may need to use `before insert` and getting the auto_incremented primary key value is not straight forward to be set for another column.

`after insert` trigger meaning the insert already happened and you can use the inserted values or values before insert using `new` and `old` keyword. In your case you want to mimic the other column value with the primary key value within the trigger and with `after insert` though you can easily get the inserted primary key value as `new.iBmsId` but you can not update the same table. So it needs to `before insert` if you want it to be done with trigger.

Here how you can do it

```
delimiter //
create trigger t_bms_ID_Update before insert on t_bms 
for each row
 begin
  SET new.id = (select iBmsId from t_bms order by iBmsId DESC LIMIT 1) + 1;
end ;//

delimiter ;
```

Now if your table is empty and you are inserting for the first time then with the above trigger you may get the `id` value as null so a better version of the above to take care of it would be as

```
delimiter //
create trigger t_bms_ID_Update before insert on t_bms 
for each row
 begin
  declare new_id int;
  SET new_id = (select iBmsId from t_bms order by iBmsId DESC LIMIT 1) + 1;
  if new_id is null then
   set new_id = 1;
  end if ;
  set new.id = new_id ;
end ;//

delimiter ;
```

Here is a test case,

```
mysql> create table test (id int, mimic int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.15 sec)


mysql> delimiter //
mysql> create trigger test_ins before insert on test
    -> for each row 
    ->  begin
    ->  declare new_mimic int;
    ->  set new_mimic = (select id from test order by id desc limit 1) + 1 ;
    ->  if new_mimic is null then 
    ->   set new_mimic = 1 ;
    ->  end if;
    ->  set new.mimic = new_mimic;
    -> end ;//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> insert into test values (1,0);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> select * from test ;
+------+-------+
| id   | mimic |
+------+-------+
|    1 |     1 |
+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test values (2,0);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> select * from test ;
+------+-------+
| id   | mimic |
+------+-------+
|    1 |     1 |
|    2 |     2 |
+------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: why do you use "for each row"? i only want the value added to the new row that was created on insert.

Comment: check the trigger syntax http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html it does not matter if you want to update one or many its an essential part of the trigger syntax

Comment: create trigger t_bms_ID_Update before insert on t_bms 
for each row
 begin
  SET new.id = (select iBmsId from t_bms order by iBmsId DESC LIMIT 1) + 1;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Comment: did you add the delimiter as I shown ? Where are you writing the trigger in mysql terminal or some other client like phpmyadmin ? If phpmyadmin then you may need to check this link http://phpsblog.agustinvillalba.com/create-triggers-phpmyadmin/

Comment: aha, no i wasn't including the delimeter, got it. FYI am using phpmyadmin, now I get this:
#1227 - Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation 
Contacting my server support now! Hopefully this is going to work as expected, thanks. i will mark question answered once i get it running.